# ConnectionPool issues: The current TransactionScope is already complete

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have an app that performs really well most of the time with 150+ requests per minute. This is hosted on Azure with Azure SQL Server on the backend. We connect to the database with EF Core 6 and Dapper with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.

We recently (in the last few months) upgraded to .NET 6 and every month or so do an update on DLLs to ensure that we have the latest dlls without vulnerabilities. For the last for weeks,   I get a spike of errors a few times a day all with the exception `The current TransactionScope is already complete.` This isn't isolated to just one call or even just EF Core. We get it on both the EF Core connections and Dapper connections, but it only lasts for a minute or so but is blocking during that time.

App Insights reports the stacktrace as follows:

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.get_Current (System.Transactions.Local, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetFromTransactedPool (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5)
```

We do use TransactionScope at some parts of the app, but strangely not in any place I've found so far where we are getting this issue.

I am also seeing this in places not necessarily related to database calls. I see the same error, but bubbling up from the ServiceBus library when trying to send messages to a queue (none of this is wrapped in a TransactionScope):

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The current TransactionScope is already complete.
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.get_Current()
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Core.BasicRetryPolicy.ShouldRetryException(Exception exception)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Core.BasicRetryPolicy.CalculateRetryDelay(Exception lastException, Int32 attemptCount)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusRetryPolicy.RunOperation[T1,TResult](Func`4 operation, T1 t1, TransportConnectionScope scope, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean logTimeoutRetriesAsVerbose)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusRetryPolicy.RunOperation[T1](Func`4 operation, T1 t1, TransportConnectionScope scope, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpSender.SendAsync(IReadOnlyCollection`1 messages, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusSender.SendMessagesAsync(IEnumerable`1 messages, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Any ideas on this? Should I just stop the auto-enlist in transactions in my connection strings??

Comment: Are you always disposing your dbcontext, connection and transaction objects with `using`?

Comment: TransactionObjects - yes. DbContext is created and disposed with DI in a Scoped lifecycle. Connections are vast throughout the app but we have been really good about putting them in using, I'm confident that they are all in usings. I had wondered about the DbContext in DI but the more I've looked into it, I don't think it is the problem. Are you thinking that I have connections that aren't getting closed?

Comment: Somethiing somewhere looks like it's not being disposed, although I suspect it's the trasaction rather than the connection.

Comment: I am disposing them everywhere, but as I was looking through I am seeing some TransactionScope() calls in async methods. After reading https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1420 and https://medium.com/@pawel.gerr/entity-framework-core-use-transactionscope-with-caution-2d38b90980b3, I wonder if I shouldn't just remove any transaction scope in an async flow

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue, as long as you `await` all the async functions properly, rather than just abandoning them.

Comment: For anything involving transaction scope and async, it is critical to pass the async flag in the transaction scope constructor; however, honestly: I never recommend transaction scope - it invariably causes more pain than it helps; manual transactions for the win

Comment: I'm definitely missing the async flag in the constructors in the async calls. Could that be culprit do you think? I will fix that and see if it resolves my issue, but it seems so random.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Marc Gravell's comment I was able to resolve this by adding the async flag to the constructor of TransactionScope in async calls. What was crazy to me was how TransactionScope in the async call messed up calls that didn't even have the same connectionstring or the same call stack. The connectionpool was really jacked up. I would like to remove all instances of TransactionScope, but I'm not in a position to do that yet.